# launchctl list <service-name> as remote command fail to work in Yosemite

Tags: macos, launchd, osx-yosemite

With Yosemite ( 14A389 ) Version, running launchctl list  as part of remote command fail to work and return error "Could not find service ....in domain for" with error code 113. This work if you run it without a remote command. This used to work in earlier release. Any idea, why this behavior has changed? Any recommended alternative to achieve the subcommand behavior?

-Karthik

Comment: I just got a solution for this problem. Your agent should have the LimitLoadToSessionType as 'Background' for this to work. In Yosemite, the default session is Aqua.